# find rows with same value using LINQ

Tags: linq, c3.js

[image: Screen Shot from MS SQL Server Management Studio]

The issue with the image above is that

- I want to apply a bonus share to the shareholders based on the TransLog_Date
- Because the shareholder in row 1 has already transferred a portion of his shares to the holder in row 3, his new share value is what shows in row 2 column 5 as 100000
- I want the bonus share to be calculated based on the value in row 2, column 5 but not on row 1, column 5.
- I have tried several codes in LINQ but getting it wrong as the value is multiplied on all the 3 records which is totally wrong.

  ```
      var transQuery = (from tq in db.TransactionsLogDbSet
                        where (tq.TransactionType == TransactionType.PurchaseOfShares)
                           || (tq.TransactionType == TransactionType.TransferOfShares) 
                           || (tq.TransactionType == TransactionType.BonusSharesDeclared)
                        select tq);

      var query = from row in db.TransactionsLogDbSet 
                  group row by row.Transholder_ID into g
                  select new { Count = g.Count() };
  ```

Comment: After having read your question multiple times, it's still completely unclear to me what you try to achieve. Can you please edit the question? If you write "based on something", specify *in what way* it should be based on that thing. Something like "Given all the transaction log records of a transaction holder (identified by `Transholder_ID'), I want to calculate a bonus based on these rules: ..."

Comment: Specifically, I want to select only rows 2 and 3 and apply the bonus shares declared on them based on the fact that row 1 as at the time of declaration of the bonus share, it has already transferred a portion of its shareholding to the shareholder in row 3

Comment: So rows 2 and 3 are different from row 1 by what criteria? How would you define "the fact that row 1 as at the time of declaration of the bonus share, it has already transferred a portion of its shareholding to the shareholder in row 3" in general terms?

Comment: Please, explain in programming way: which rows do you want to select? Which 'same value'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, i think I finally got what you want.

Is that right?: Group all rows of some `TransactionType`s by the `Transholder_ID`, then from each group select the row with the maximum `Translog_Date`, giving you the most recent row per `Transholder_ID`. Once you have the result of that, you can iterate over it to calculate whatever you need.

```
from t in db.TransactionLogDbSet
where where tq.TransactionType == TransactionType.PurchaseOfShares || tq.TransactionType == TransactionType.TransferOfShares || tq.TransactionType == TransactionType.BonusSharesDeclared
group t by t.Transholder_ID into g
select (from t1 in g orderby t1.Translog_Date descending select t1).First();
```

**EDIT**: I'll continue to edit the following part of my answer as long as we finally arrive at the correct query.

From you last comment so far it follows that you just want to select all rows with a `TransLog_Date` <= a given `DateTime qualifiedDate`.

```
from t in db.TransactionLogDbSet
where t.TransactionLog_Date <= qualifiedDate
select t
```

Is that it?

Comment: Tinudu, thanks for your solution. My another question is that what if the shareholder who transferred a portion of his shareholdings to another shareholder purchased a share after the transfer and the date also qualifies for the bonus share? Can you please help me with this scenario?

Comment: Are you saying that there are possibly multiple rows per `Transholder_ID` that qualify for a bonus and therefore should show up in the result? How would you express "transferred a portion to another shareholder" in terms of your data model? is it `TransLog_Debit > 0`? Still got the feeling you give us not all the information that is needed.

Comment: What I mean is that assuming Mr 'A' has a shareholding of 500 and transferred a portion of 200 to Mr 'B'. Now he (Mr 'A') has a remaining of 300 shareholding. At another date, Mr 'A' bought a share of 100 and Mr 'B' also bought 50 shares. Later on, a bonus share was declared in which the dates for both transfer and purchase of the shares are qualified except the first date purchased of 500 by Mr 'A'. How do I treat this?

Comment: I asked about your your rules expressed *in terms of your data model*. How do the rows look like in the example you give, and how would you identify qualifying rows based on the rows' properties? Answer that question and you'll probably be able to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: The rules are the same as the code you helped me with but my problem is that if two rows belong to the same shareholder and those two also qualifies. Each row is identified by the Transholder_ID though it has a key I don't use that since it is not related to the main transaction table

Comment: Each row is identified by the `TransLog_ID`, right? Several rows are related to a shareholder through their `Transholder_ID`, right? A row qualifies for the bonus if ... << (here comes your text *in terms of the data model*).

Comment: Yes, a row qualifies for shares if its purchased date is <= to the qualified date specified.

Comment: Which of your fields is the "purchased date"? What is "the qualified date specified"? Haven't seen it mentioned so far. Don't get bored by my questions, I'm trying to help you formulate your requirements...

Comment: The purchase date is TransLog_Date in the code you corrected and the Qualified_Date is defined not in the table but retrieved from a different table in the database and then compared with the TransLog_Date field value. I am 100% happy with your questions as it is even making me think deeper!

Comment: I am still waiting for your response please

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect the requirement you gave (`TransactionLog_Date <= qualifiedDate`), asking you whether you're happy with it. If you aren't you have to tell what else you expect it to include.